# Odoo v8 server won't start from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, odoo, openerp-8

I am trying to start Odoo v8 server from Eclipse ide. I have set the debug configurations and have given the config file path in the arguments as

```
-c /etc/odoo-server.conf.
```

When I do debug as python run, I do not get any error. The log file also does not show any error. But when I open *localhost:8069* from the browser.

I get server not found error. This does not happen when I start the server through the terminal. Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem?

Below is the odoo-server.conf content:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
```

Below is the server traceback:

```
2014-11-15 07:47:06,205 3875 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0 
2014-11-15 07:47:06,206 3875 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/hassan/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons'] 
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost 
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432 
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo 
2014-11-15 07:47:07,046 3875 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Evented Service (longpolling) running on 0.0.0.0:8072
```

Comment: can you paste your server traceback?

Comment: 2014-11-15 07:47:06,205 3875 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0
2014-11-15 07:47:06,206 3875 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/hassan/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-11-15 07:47:06,207 3875 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2014-11-15 07:47:07,046 3875 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Evented Service (longpolling) running on 0.0.0.0:8072

Comment: I can see that the werkzeug service on 8069 is not running. But I am unable to find the reason

Comment: After whole day of R&D, I found out that this issue is due a bug in the latest PyDev plugin for eclipse. I downgraded the plugin and now it is working fine.

Comment: @Hassan Zaheer, to which version did you **DOWNGRADE**?

Comment: after downgrading Pydev plugin to **3.5.0**, the odoo.py server starts fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check whether the configuration file that you have set is having appropriate access rights. And try not to log the errors into a file, instead allow it show it on the console on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Config file has complete access 777 and is owned by odoo:admin

Comment: @HassanZaheer 
Can you share your config file here?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your "traceback": is a normal log, with only `INFO` messages and it tells you that the server is running and waiting for requests on port 8072.

Point a browser at `http://localhost:8072` and you should see a login page.

Comment: LOL, this is the only correct answer and somebody gave it a downvote. If OP doesn't want to use "Evented Service", it's enough to just remove python package gevent from your environment.

Comment: 8072 is the longpolling port. The problem OP is facing is that 8069 thread doesn't start, yet 8072 does start.

Answer (score -1):

I know my answer is late, but i ran into this problem today, and got the server running, so thought I should share : 
Do not start the openerp server as : Debug as -> Python run.
It only starts the longpolling service.
Try running as : **Run as -> Python run**
This will start the Http service at your defined port or by default at 8069.